# 3 octave A Major violin scale fingerings?

Tags: scales, fingering, violin

What are some common fingerings for a 3 octave A major scale on violin?

Comment: My children play viola.  They were given a weird scale fingering (I'm a cellist).  You plan ahead to use the fourth finger on the second to last note at the top, then eek that finger up to play the top note.  Then eek it down again for the second-to-last note on the way down.  Even though it strikes me as weird, it does seem to work pretty darn well.  I think that's because the fingers are so close together at the top on violin and viola.  However, you could alternatively plan ahead to land on the top note with the fourth finger instead, and see which approach you like better.

Comment: Now, whether you want to switch early or late (on the way up) to the E string: there is a timbre difference and in a particular piece this would influence your choice. / I think you can google or youtube-search for scale fingerings.  I don't remember the details now that I'm not the Suzuki parent coach anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The standard fingering (e.g. Simon Fischer's "Scales" book) is:

First position up to C#4 (second finger on the A string).
Then shift up to 3rd position for the D4, 1st finger.
Stay in 3rd up to and including C#5 (3rd finger on the E string).
Then shift up to 7th position for the D5, 1st finger.
Stay in 7th up to the penultimate note, G#, 4th finger, before a half finger stretch to play the final A with 4th finger, followed by the G# again with the 4th.
Come back down the same way you went up.
So, after D5 on 1st finger, C#5 on 1st finger, etc.

If you play your 3 octave scales in triplets (3 notes to a bow, 6 or 12, etc. notes to a bow) then you are good to go. If you play duplets (2, 4, 8, etc. notes to a bow) then you probably want to add a turn, extra notes at the beginning or end to even out the bowing.

Professor [Julia Bushkova](https://www.bushkova.com/biography) of North Texas University explains and demonstrates this and other facets of 3 octave scales in her YouTube video: